# Using foreach in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to save data that is returned in array form to my table. However, I need to access the string in both GET inputs to do so. How can I achieve that? I can do it with one GET but not both.

```
    public function postDisableDates() {

    $input = Input::all();  

    foreach($input['date'] as $date) {

        $db_date = strtotime($date);

        $dateFormat = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month", $db_date));

    DB::table('bk_disable_date')
            ->delete();

    DB::table('bk_disable_date')
            ->insert(array(
                'date' => $dateFormat,
                'office' => $input['office']
            ));                     
    }       

}
```

**var dump $input**

```
array(3) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "Dr0pu8RUbTTe1t058Fb3sDjKQLLk1KMBnBrpV7m6" ["office"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "Office1" [1]=> string(10) "Office2" [2]=> string(10) "Office3" [3]=> string(10) "Office4" } ["date"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(17) "25 December, 2013" [1]=> string(17) "14 December, 2013" [2]=> string(17) "05 December, 2013" [3]=> string(17) "23 November, 2013" } }
```

**var dump of $dateFormat in foreach loop**

```
string(10) "2013-11-25" string(10) "2013-11-14" string(10) "2013-11-05" string(10) "2013-10-23"
```

The $dateFormat part seems to be ok. I just need the office part to work the same way. Probably an easier way to achieve this.

my input names are set up as office[] and date[]. If that helps.

**The disable date table is as follows**

```
id  date    office
30  2013-11-25  Office1
31  2013-11-14  Office2
32  2013-11-05  Office3
33  2013-10-23  Office4
```

Comment: So your values are not sent over to you as key value pairs within objects or arrays and therefore are just consecutive, such as form submission, `date[]=2013/11/10&office[]=somewhere&date[]=2013/11/11&office[]=elsewhere` and so on and so forth?

Comment: Looks like they are being sent via array: array(3) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "Dr0pu8RUbTTe1t058Fb3sDjKQLLk1KMBnBrpV7m6" ["office"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "Office1" [1]=> string(10) "Office2" [2]=> string(10) "Office3" [3]=> string(10) "Office4" } ["date"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(17) "25 December, 2013" [1]=> string(17) "14 December, 2013" [2]=> string(17) "05 December, 2013" [3]=> string(17) "23 November, 2013" } }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the office and date keys are the same (which I assume), you could try that:

```
public function postDisableDates() {

  $input = Input::all();  

  DB::table('bk_disable_date')
    ->delete();

  foreach($input['date'] as $key => $date) {

    $db_date = strtotime($date);
    $dateFormat = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month", $db_date));

    DB::table('bk_disable_date')
      ->insert(array(
        'date' => $dateFormat,
        'office' => $input['office'][$key]
      )
    );                     
  }       
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That's a start but it's only saving the first row. But it does save correctly.

Comment: @Lynx: I only see one row in your example, don't I?

Comment: No, sorry I must not have explained it correctly. It's a row of data. so office would have 'Office1', 'Office2'..etc...and dates go along with those offices. I will edit my question to show how the data is saving.

Comment: See edit for format of table to get an idea of what i am trying to achieve

Comment: @Lynx: I removed the delete from the `foreach`. That does not seem right the delete the table everytime before inserting the new row. If you want to have a fresh start, the delete should be before the `foreach`.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense lol. It seem to work ok now but now it's having an issue when I add a row (via front-end jquery) it's just seperating each letter in the first office. as noted by this dump $input['office'][$key]: string(1) "B" string(1) "i" string(1) "r" string(1) "m" string(1) "i" string(1) "n" string(1) "g"